# How to print all element of the list and not only the last one?

Tags: python, list

I wrote a script that allows me to extract through a loop all the floating numbers and put them in a list, then display this list with all the extracted floating numbers except that in my script only the last number of each list is taken into account, while I would like all the numbers to be displayed. how to do it?

there is my code :

```
final_result = []
result = []
k = listFps
k = 0

while k < len(listFps):
    with open(listFps[k], 'r') as f:
        #
        statList = f.readlines()
        statList = [x.strip() for x in statList]
        for line in statList:
            if (re.search("=", str(line))):
                if (re.search('#IND', str(line))):
                    print("ok")
                else:
                    result =re.findall("=\s*?(\d+\.\d+|\d+)", str(line))

                    print (" ca c result " ,result)

     numberList = [float(q) for q in result]
     print("ca c number list :",numberList)

     k+=1
```

its print me only the last element of my list like this :

```
[59.889]
[60.874]
```

etc..
    But i actually want a list with all element :

```
[59.889,60.874....]
```

Help me please im stuck with it for too long..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
result = re.findall….
```

use

```
result += re.findall…
```

Comment: it worked with the first iteration ( the first list ) when i increment k (on my loop ) the second list got the entire first list at the begining, do you know why ? @scott Hunter

Comment: you haven't reset `result` to `[]`

Comment: when i have to reset it ? on my loop ? can u show me on my code please im not an expert on python and thats a homework so im really stuck please

Comment: i found it, it worked perfectly really thank you ! Both of you